# Perform jQuery selection on ajaxed html content

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to load an html document using ajax and then perform a jquery selection on the loaded html?

I want to perform a search against a remote search server and then use the results to reformat an existing page.

**EDIT**: the find function doesnt seem to return results (length is always 0). Here is the sample html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Hello world</p>

    <p>good bye world</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'content/HTMLPage.htm',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {

      alert($(data).find('p').length);

    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really struggled with this. I have managed to load a whole document and select from it correctly, but this one had a doctype.

Otherwise it seems it is possible but it has its caveats. The items you are selecting need to have at least a parent node. I dont really think I can mark anything off here as an answer just yet.

This html returned 2 elements:

```
<div>
  <p>Hello world</p>

  <p>good bye world</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, if you can...

You just could use

```
var result = $(returned_html) ;
```

within the ajax success handler, and then do `result.find('#id_of_anything')`.
Your ajax call should have a 'dataType' of 'html' here.

Your problem is, "remote search server" invokes a 'remote domain', which will not
possible due to ajax same-origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

*Is it possible to load an html document using ajax and then perform a jquery selection on the loaded html?* - **Yes**

You can handle events by using [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: Note, I'm not loading this into the DOM of the page, so live() and delegate() are not relevant here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$.get(url, function(data) {

  $(data).find();

} );
```

You basically wrap the returned html content in an jQuery object. Then you can use jQuery selectors with it.